# Any restrictions by other states -- Provisional License Driving

Tags: usa

My daughter will be driving from Maryland to Kentucky, using a provisional drivers license. She is 20 years old. Are there any restrictions?

Comment: You (or we) would need to know the route, because the laws in this case are all State and therefor are varied.

Comment: I agree - please edit the question to contain the route.  And by "provisional" do you mean a learner's license, or a graduated-type full license with restrictions?  The former are generally not valid out of their jurisdiction, and the latter generally are valid subject to their restrictions.